# Glitches between using scalable and non scalable units

Tags: css, reactjs

So I'm trying to style links on a navigation bar using CSS. When I set the space property between links using a set pixel value, it works perfectly.

```
padding: 0 3rem;
```

However, when I replace this line to use the following code for scalability

```
padding-left: 15%;
```

It causes a glitch on my screen where it is close together and then expands as I click them. [Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKfec.png)
After various interactions, the links padding slowly expand to the proper size. [After some interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbVbl.png) Then when I press a link, (which hasn't been set to anything yet, so it goes back to the home page), the padding goes back to 0. The code works perfectly across devices within console however, just not on the browser as I test it. Does this have to do with React improperly calculating padding percentages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it is doing that. Have you tried using Flexbox?

If you set the parent element to `display: flex` you can use `justify-content: space-around` to spread the links out within the parent container.

Then you can add media queries and control the total size of the parent container instead of trying to calculate the spaces in em or rem. Flexbox will automatically space the links evenly.

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/nick_kinlen/pen/eYNKbrX).

Comment: Worked like a charm!